# Plus sign changes to minus when accordion submenu opens, but doesn't change back when submenu closes

Tags: jquery

I am learning JQuery and I've been trying to make an accordion menu with submenus that appear and disappear on click, as well as a plus sign when the submenu is closed and a minus sign when it's opened.
It does change to - when I open it, but I can't get it to change when the submenu closes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".h").click(function() {
    $(this).next("p").slideToggle();

    if ( $(this).next("p").css('display') == 'block') {
      $(this).children("h6").text('-');
    } else {
      $(this).children("h6").text('+');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="acc">

  <div class="acc">
    <div class="h">
      <h5>Contenu 1</h5>
      <h6>+</h6>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum quis dignissim odio. Mauris vel nisi a dui dignissim interdum. Quisque eu euismod sapien. Ut tincidunt convallis diam in pretium. Mauris pharetra suscipit turpis et porta. Maecenas
      tristique, ligula in fringilla faucibus, ligula mi suscipit justo, eget tristique neque massa eget quam.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="acc">
    <div class="h">
      <h5>Contenu 2</h5>
      <h6>+</h6>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum quis dignissim odio. Mauris vel nisi a dui dignissim interdum. Quisque eu euismod sapien. Ut tincidunt convallis diam in pretium. Mauris pharetra suscipit turpis et porta. Maecenas
      tristique, ligula in fringilla faucibus, ligula mi suscipit justo, eget tristique neque massa eget quam.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="acc">
    <div class="h">
      <h5>Contenu 3</h5>
      <h6>+</h6>
    </div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum quis dignissim odio. Mauris vel nisi a dui dignissim interdum. Quisque eu euismod sapien. Ut tincidunt convallis diam in pretium. Mauris pharetra suscipit turpis et porta. Maecenas
      tristique, ligula in fringilla faucibus, ligula mi suscipit justo, eget tristique neque massa eget quam.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(this).next("p").css` is a function, it's always true. What are you trying to do with that condition? You need to *call* the function and compare the result with something.

Comment: I suspect what you want is `if ($(this).next("p").is(":visible"))`